# at org.testng.xml.XmlUtils.dumpParameters(XmlUtils.java:26)

Tags: java, testng

I am facing issue in TestNg ,I am getting test cases executed fine,But i am getting errror in report as below.
May anyone please guide me what can be issue.
It mentions no line from my code.

```
    [TestNG] Reporter org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@3a3e78f failed
    java.lang.NullPointerException
       at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
       at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:166)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlUtils.dumpParameters(XmlUtils.java:26)
       at org.testng.xml.DefaultXmlWeaver.asXml(DefaultXmlWeaver.java:184)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlWeaver.asXml(XmlWeaver.java:67)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlTest.toXml(XmlTest.java:475)
       at org.testng.xml.DefaultXmlWeaver.asXml(DefaultXmlWeaver.java:139)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlWeaver.asXml(XmlWeaver.java:57)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlSuite.toXml(XmlSuite.java:518)
       at org.testng.reporters.jq.TestNgXmlPanel.getContent(TestNgXmlPanel.java:28)
       at org.testng.reporters.jq.BaseMultiSuitePanel.generate(BaseMultiSuitePanel.java:24)
       at org.testng.reporters.jq.Main.generateReport(Main.java:65)
       at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1076)
       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1001)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
[TestNG] Reporter org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@4e858e0a failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
       at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:166)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlUtils.dumpParameters(XmlUtils.java:26)
       at org.testng.xml.DefaultXmlWeaver.asXml(DefaultXmlWeaver.java:184)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlWeaver.asXml(XmlWeaver.java:67)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlTest.toXml(XmlTest.java:475)
       at org.testng.xml.DefaultXmlWeaver.asXml(DefaultXmlWeaver.java:139)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlWeaver.asXml(XmlWeaver.java:57)
       at org.testng.xml.XmlSuite.toXml(XmlSuite.java:518)
       at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateXmlFile(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:94)
       at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateReport(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:79)
       at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1076)
       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1001)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped:
```

Comment: Could you open a new issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues and provide a runnable sample that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no,It was working fine till 3 days ,we didnt change version etc,we started using ITestContext,ITestResults in our code and this error started coming.

Comment: @hemantsablok - If you aren't going to be able to provide a sample, how do you expect this issue to be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found issue, it was occurring due to reason that I was setting a parameter without a value. Somehow reporting system is failing with it. Where as my test case was running fine.

Comment: Again, could you open an issue? TestNG is supposed to provide a better message in such cases.